# How to change zipcode in the geolocation searchbox and find the price of a product as per the url through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, findelement

I am trying to get the prices of this rice cracker (https://www.sayweee.com/en/product/Want-Want-Senbei-Rice-Crackers/17119) using different zip codes inputting into the geolocation searchbox, and the zipcodes I used are from my GCP pub/sub topic message. I use `selenium` to do this staff, but I cannot find a correct way to locate the zipcode and change it.
My script is like this:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Set up Pub/Sub subscription
project_id = "my-project"
subscription_name = "my-subscription"
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_name)

def callback(message):
    try:
        # Get the zip code from the message
        zip_code = message.data.decode('utf-8')
        
        # Load the webpage with the zip code
        url = 'https://www.sayweee.com/en/product/Want-Want-Senbei-Rice-Crackers/17119'
        driver.get(url)
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'zipcode-input').send_keys(zip_code)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div').click()
        
        # Extract the price from the webpage
        next_data_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//script[@type='application/ld+json']")
        next_data_text = next_data_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
        next_data_start_index = next_data_text.index('{')
        next_data_end_index = next_data_text.rindex('}') + 1
        next_data_json = next_data_text[next_data_start_index:next_data_end_index]
        next_data = json.loads(next_data_json)
        price = next_data['offers']['price']
        
        # Print the result
        print(f"Price of rice crackers in zip code {zip_code}: {price}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing message: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        message.ack()

subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

I tried `selenium` and locate the zipcode with `ID` and `XPATH`. I am wondering whether a popup when opening this url page may influence the locating process and I am not sure if the `XPATH` I used here is correct. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction? Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: I don't see any element with ID `zipcode-input` on your mentioned URL